# How do I get back a bounty, when I found the solution by myself?

Tags: discussion, bounty

How do I get back a bounty, when found the solution by myself?

I answered my question by myself. How can I get back the bounty?

*[How to use the delegates with NSKeyedUnarchiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824624/how-to-use-the-delegates-with-nskeyedunarchiver)*

Comment: See: [help/bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) : **`All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances.`**

Comment: Per the help center [bounties are non-refundable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Comment: You can't. Bounties are a way to attract attention to your question, and that did happen even if you have found the answer yourself. Refunding happens very rarely and I don't think your case would qualify.

Comment: Thats ok. Good to know and it make sense also to me.

Answer (score 26):

Bounties are non-refundable. In very, very specific cases, moderators can manually refund them, but your case doesn't qualify here.

With the bounty, you "paid" for additional attention on your question. Whether that attention was attention that could have answered your question is simply the gamble you make.

Comment: In what cases do moderators refund bounties?

Comment: what if I delete that question?

Comment: I repeat the question, in what cases do moderators refund bounties? It's interesting to know, unless you're not allowed to share that information.

Comment: @Islam Usually in cases where it's an obvious mistake (and caught early), or when people are using them to build up sockpuppets.

Comment: @Undo In my opinion, this rule needs to be reviewed. I disagree in one specific case and if taken to a vote, I am certain most will agree. While I do understand and agree that these bounties are non-refundable and also that you "pay" for exposure, it also benefits the community to drive answers. I paid to help that, not just myself but the community. To add insult to injury, if anybody else answers, they get the bounty but if I end up finding the answer myself, it only makes sense that I receive the bounty, just like anybody else would, since I provided the answer and helped the community.

Comment: A change to the system like that deserves its own question, @MichaelBedford. This is a pretty complex subject that can't be hashed out in a single comment thread.

Comment: Understood, I will do that. How do I post a general question like this?

Comment: @MichaelBedford Probably https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask, tag it [discussion].

Answer (score -4):

You know what; i got my bounty back that i bet on a useless question. Well getting your bounty is not possible by only your own but you may get it back when that question would be paused or deleted in your bounty days. I got that golden bird by a moderator on StackOverflow and the question got on hold because of too broad description; which helped me get my bounty back. Well; this is the end of my happy story :)

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted. It actually could be useful. It's a case where you get your bounty back.