# Gave bounty to a wrong answer, what can I do?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

I've set a bounty of 50 reputation points and accidentally gave it to the [wrong answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71843776/8099601).

How can I take it back and give it to the right answer?

Comment: You can't, you'll just need to be more careful in future. If you get some more rep you can always create another bounty for the right answer.

Comment: @RobertLongson but according to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314963/17133283) post, moderators can.

Comment: Mods also can't reverse it or reassign it. If you've awarded it, that's it. Your only option is to create a new one, but that one would have to be for 100 rep

Comment: @Sambhav.K That's only prior to awarding; we can cancel active bounties, but we cannot do anything about awarded ones

Comment: Cross-site duplicate on MSE: [I accidentally gave the wrong person a bounty, who can I contact to undo?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200244/348196) And a related feature request: [Should we allow to undo a mistaken bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257105/348196)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Help Center's [bounty page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) (emphasis mine):

> All bounties are paid for up front and **non-refundable** *under any circumstances*

Note that re-assigning involves "refunding" first and can't be done either, including diamond mods based on [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417520/gave-bounty-to-a-wrong-answer-what-can-i-do#comment905265_417520) by [Zoe stands with Ukraine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6296561/zoe-stands-with-ukraine):

> Mods also can't reverse it or reassign it. If you've awarded it, that's it. ... we can cancel active bounties, but we cannot do anything about awarded ones.

Comment: This is not a request for a refund though, it's a request for a move.

Comment: @RobertLongson:  To move the bounty, you'd have to refund it from one account and apply it to another.  Because you can't refund it, you can't move it.

Comment: Every single time I see information about how the bounty system works, my opinion of it lowers. This is no exception.